# Index to enforce a single TRUE value per table in bit column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table that contains an IsDefault column:

```
CREATE TABLE CustomerType
(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Name nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    IsDefault bit NOT NULL
)
```

The IsDefault value should, naturally, be `TRUE` for only a single row, all other rows should be `FALSE`. I want to enforce this rule on the database level.

Currently I achieve this by adding a new computed column and placing a UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX on it:

```
CREATE TABLE CustomerType
(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Name nvarchar(50) NULL,
    IsDefault bit NOT NULL
    IsDefaultConstraint AS (CASE WHEN IsDefault = 1 THEN 1 ELSE -ID END),
)

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX UQ_CustomerType_IsDefault ON CustomerType
(
    IsDefaultConstraint ASC
)
```

This works just fine, but has a bit of code smell to it because the extra column doesn't contain relevant data and is just used for enforcing the unique index.

Are there alternative ways to enforce the same behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SQL Server 2008 or later, use a [filtered index](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_Default on CustomerType (IsDefault) WHERE IsDefault = 1
```

For older versions, you use the "poor man's filtered index", the [indexed view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx):

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.DRI_CustomerType_Default
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   SELECT IsDefault FROM dbo.CustomerType WHERE IsDefault = 1
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_Default on DRI_CustomerType_Default (IsDefault)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately SQL-Server doesn't provide function based indexes, which is what you are looking for. So your approach is the best available.

If the additional column is too annoying, then use a view on the table hiding that column.

If this is still annoying you, switch to Oracle ;-)

Comment: Have you ever tried finding an answer on the Oracle forums? I would rather use a paper-based database than getting anywhere near Oracle for the sole reason that it is simply awful to try to get any sort of help from https://communities.oracle.com/

Comment: SQL Server has only had filtered indexes for 5 years. And for this problem, a filtered index can be simulated with indexed views, which have been around since at least the 2000 version of the product.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about filtered indexes. Looks like a great feature.